# Would like to extract text from a website with excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, web

i current have the following code which is not working giving me a object variable or with block variable not set.

```
Set doc = IE.document
Dim sDD4 As String
sDD4 = Trim(doc.getElementById("productInfoContainter").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText)
Sheet1.Cells(i, 8) = sDD4
```

the html im trying to extract from looks like this:

```
<div id="productInfoContainter" style="display: block;">
<table width="100%" style="display: none;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <div style="margin: 5px;"> 
                    <span class="notranslate" onmouseover="_tipon(this)" onmouseout="_tipoff()">
                        <span class="google-src-text" style="text-align: left; direction: ltr;">
                            <b>text i need 1</b>
                        </span> 
                            <b>text i need 2</b>
                    </span> 
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <div style="margin: 10px 10px 20px;" itemprop="description"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i have also tried getElementbyClassName("google-src-text")(0).innerText

comes up with the same error.

basically i am trying to translate a website in google translate the take out a body of the translated text

any help appreciated

Comment: I'm betting that `productInfoContainter` is a typo.

Comment: Is the first few lines the simplified version of the code. As i do not see you opening the website? or setting doc.navigate and i see that you are calling the code from excel based on your tags. Have you set the references to use the Internet Controls?

Answer (score 0):

The code I would expect is something like this

```
Sub WebNavigate()
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    WebSite = "www.YourWebsite.com/Links"
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate WebSite
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set Element = .document.getElementById("productInfoContainter")
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 8) = Element.innertext
        End With

End Sub
```